# Sprite kit can't run action before switch to new scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

Actions don't run in this code:

```
 SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveToX:(-800) duration:0.6];
 SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveToX:(800) duration:0.6];
 [_labelLogo runAction:moveLeft];
 [_labelPlay runAction:moveRight];  

 NewYork *start = [[NewYork alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
 SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] duration:2];
 reveal.pausesIncomingScene = NO;

 [self.scene.view presentScene: start transition: reveal];
```

If i comment NewYork switching they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem to action *moveLeft / *moveRight, its because start immediately the transition to NewYork scene, so you should wait that *moveLeft / *moveRight is finished like this:

```
 SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveToX:(-800) duration:0.6];
 SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveToX:(800) duration:0.6];
 [_labelLogo runAction:moveLeft];

 [_labelPlay runAction:moveRight completion:^{

    NewYork *start = [[NewYork alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] duration:2];
    reveal.pausesIncomingScene = NO;

    [self.view presentScene:start transition:reveal];
 }];
```

Comment: self.scene.view (any node) or self.view (the scene) both work depending on what node class it is.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thank you for comment and upvote, what do you means for "what node class it is" ? for example? thanks again

Comment: I'm saying whether you do [self.scene.view presentScene:start transition:reveal]; or [self.view presentScene:start transition:reveal]; makes absolutely no difference whatsoever. Unless you're trying to do the latter in a node object that is not a SKScene class, where it will be a compile error (only SKScene has a view property, all other nodes have to go through self.scene.view).

Comment: Thank you, it works, but i can't understand why in my initial code it starts first scene transition instead actions, they are before the transitions.Does this mean that whatever i want to occur after the action i have to put the code in the block instead simply on the next line?

Comment: @user1614097 they are before the transition but the program arriving earlier than 0.6 seconds to "presentScene" and so the actions are stopped. yes exactly, when you do something after an action put the code in block